# How to make my car realize my phone's system sounds aren't music?

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode

I recently got a new BlackBerry Priv, and it works pretty well so far, but when I plugged it into my car's USB port to recharge, I ran into an unpleasant surprise: the entertainment system (Ford Sync) scanned it for media and then switched away from the radio and started playing all of the phone's built-in system notification sound effects in an endless loop.  For some bizarre reason, it appears to think that they're music on my device!

Is there anything I can do on the phone to make the system sound effects stay private so the car doesn't think they're "media"?

Comment: This really depends on how Ford Sync scans the device, not Android. On Android, you can have a music app ignore a directory by placing a file `.nomedia` in it.